# How to sum a column based on a non-mutually exclusive condition?

Tags: sql-server, google-bigquery

Say I have data as:

```
TextColumn | ValueColumn
-----------|------------
a          | 1
a          | 1
ab         | 1
b          | 2
b          | 2
```

How can I get the following result?

```
SELECT CASE WHEN TextColumn LIKE '%a%' THEN 'a' WHEN TextColumn LIKE '%b%' THEN 'b' END AS TextGroup, SUM(ValueColumn) AS GroupSum FROM <Table>
GROUP BY TextGroup
```

This should return:

```
TextGroup | GroupSum
----------|---------
a         | 3
b         | 5
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming this is an abstract and you will be defining your `TextGroup` values

**Example**

```
Select TextGroup 
      ,GroupSum = sum(ValueColumn)
 From  (values  ('a')
               ,('b')
      )A(TextGroup)
 Join YourTable B on charindex(TextGroup,[TextColumn])>0
 Group By TextGroup
```

**Results**

```
TextGroup   GroupSum
a           3
b           5
```

EDIT:  Another option

```
Declare @TextGroups varchar(max) = 'a,b'
 
Select TextGroup = A.value
      ,GroupSum = sum(ValueColumn)
 From  string_split(@TextGroups,',') A
 Join YourTable B on charindex(A.value,[TextColumn])>0
 Group By A.value
```

**Note:**
You can use a LEFT JOIN if you want to see the missed values (NULL's)

Comment: Is there a similar way to handle this same issue but with LIKE conditions instead of pure character indexing?

Comment: @jpkey Sure   in the 1st example ...  on [TextColumn] like '%'+A.TextGroup+'%'     In the 2nd example:  ...  on [TextColumn] like '%'+A.value+'%' ....  that said, charindex will find a string of more than 1 character.

Comment: @jpkey Take a peek at https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=d49f8dd70bc776c87835492d178d1250

Comment: Trying to convert this to BigQuery's syntax at the moment. Glad to see this works for SQL Server.

Comment: @jpkey "Tag Blindness"  I saw SQL Server and blanked on Bigquery.   Not a BQ guy.

Comment: All good. It is just standard sql. I figured nobody would answer me if I simply tagged bigquery.

Answer (score 0):

Consider below approach (BigQuery)

```
select TextGroup, sum(ValueColumn) as GroupSum
from your_table, unnest(split(TextColumn, '')) TextGroup
group by TextGroup
```

if applied to sample data in your question  - output is

[image]

Comment: I require LIKE functionality inside a WHERE clause for my use case. This does return the required result per my example in this case, however.

Comment: you might want to improve your question to have it more clear of what exactly your want/"require"! :o) and obviously, provide better example - so no confusion about what it is that you wanted to extract - I thought you just wanted to count all chars counts ...